# How to move to second view programatically in ios app?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I have App with single storyboard, and two view in same story board. First one is controlled by `ViewController` and second one is controlled by `View`.(Two different class files, one inherits `UIViewController` and another `UIView`). App loads the first story board which is linked to `UIViewController`.

Now, I want to check some conditions in `NSUserDefaults` and skip the first view on app load if the condition is true. Skip first view can also be automatically load second view, this what I am trying to accomplish.

I have searched a lot and all of them were about the Navigation Controller, My views/controllers are not navigation controller, also I dnt want to use that because of the automatic navigation bar which I dont want.

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: First learn the basics of Objective-C....The question itself too basic requirement or not understandable way...

Comment: you can hide navigation bar. In atrribute inspecter or programmatically  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];

Answer (score 0):

remember to import the secondView,
and in storyboard you have to give the identifier "SecondView" to secondViewController

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"Yes"]) {

   SecondViewController *sv = (SecondViewController *)[self.storyboard 
   istantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondView"];
   sv.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
   [self presentViewController:sv animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
```